# hash function that outputs integer from 0 to 255?

Tags: python, hash, integer

I need a very simple hash function in Python that will convert a string to an integer from 0 to 255.

For example:

```
>>> hash_function("abc_123")
32
>>> hash_function("any-string-value")
99
```

It does not matter what the integer is as long as I get the same integer every time I call the function.

I want to use the integer to generate a random subnet mask based on the name of the network.

Comment: How do you plan to get the hashed value back?

Comment: Your use case is fine with being able to distinguish only 256 unique values, and have anything beyond that clash? What's the issue with using a larger standard hash?

Comment: I want to use the output as part of a subnet mask in a network

Answer (score 27):

You could just use the modulus of the [`hash()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) output:

```
def onebyte_hash(s):
    return hash(s) % 256
```

This is what dictionaries and sets use (hash modulus the internal table size).

Demo:

```
>>> onebyte_hash('abc_123')
182
>>> onebyte_hash('any-string-value')
12
```

Caveat: On Python 3.3 and up, *hash randomisation* is enabled by default, and *between restarts of Python* you'll get different values. The hash, then, is only stable if you don't restart the Python process or set [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) to a fixed decimal number (with `0` disabling it altogether). On Python 2 and 3.0 through to 3.2 hash randomisation is either not available or only enabled if you set a seed explicitly.

Another alternative is to just [`hashlib.md5()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) and just take (integer value of) the first byte:

```
import hashlib

try:
    # Python 2; Python 3 will throw an exception here as bytes are required
    hashlib.md5('')
    def onebyte_hash(s):
        return ord(hashlib.md5(s).digest()[0])
except TypeError:
    # Python 3; encode the string first, return first byte
    def onebyte_hash(s):
        return hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf8')).digest()[0]
```

MD5 is a well-establish cryptographic hash, the output is stable across Python versions and independent of hash randomisation.

The disadvantage of the latter would be that it'd be marginally slower; Python caches string hashes on the string object, so retrieving the hash later on is fast and cheap most of the time.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and I get random hashes every time I run the following program. What am I doing wrong? import os
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "8675309"
print(hash('This string'))

Comment: @AlltheRage: you need to set the seed **before** you start Python, in the parent environment.

Comment: you can extend this approach to get any range, for example `int(hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf8')).hexdigest(),16) % 10000` gives a hash 0-9999. Maybe it's not optimal but that's what I used

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: then why not just [load an integer from more digest bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) instead of round-tripping the hex digest?

Comment: yeah that works too, but modulo is still in order for values that aren't 2^something